# Create dataframe with 2 columns where a one column is a sequence of 100 elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a 1d numpy array of 530 number, which I created like so, `np.array([i for i in range(530)])`. So the shape of this 1d array is `(530,)`. I also have a 2d array which is an array of 530 lists where each list contains 100 elements. To be clear the shape of this 2d array is `(530, 100)`.

`>>>indices = np.array([i for i in range(530)])`

`>>>print(test_data.shape)
 (530,100)`

Using these two arrays, `indices` and `test_data`, what I want to do is create a pandas dataframe with only 2 columns where the first column is indices(1 integer per row), and the second column is a single list(length 100) from `test_data`. The sequential nature of each arrays should be maintained, so the first int in `indices` corresponds to the first 100 length array in `test_data`.

I tried using zip with these two arrays, and then creating a dataframe but it doesn't work.

Comment: An explanation for the close would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
i = np.arange(530)                      # first column
j = np.random.randn(530, 100).tolist()  # second column
```

**Option 1**
Initialise a `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i, j]).T
```

---

**Option 2**
Initialise a `Series` (you don't even need `i` for this)

```
df = pd.Series(j).reset_index()
```